# React - Have One Main setState Function or Multiple?

Tags: reactjs

I've been developing in React for a while. When I first started, my code would look like this:

```
this.state = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
};

updateFoo(num) {
  this.setState({ foo: num )};
}

updateBar(num) {
  this.setState({ bar: num )};
}

updateBaz(num) {
  this.setState({ baz: num )};
}
```

A separate function to update a separate part of state.

Later on I realized, hmm that is pretty dedundant, let's change things up. So instead of a separate function for each state update, I went to something like this:

```
updateState(key, val) {
  this.setState([key]: val);
}
```

I've been using **updateState** for very simple state updates for a little while now. I like it but I realized that I can go a step further and pass an entire update object for updating multiple states:

```
updateManyStates(state) {
  this.setState(state);
}

updateManyStates({ foo: 5, bar: 6, baz: 7 });
```

After writing the **updateManyStates** function I felt my code was becoming less clear. Though redundant, the functions like **updateFoo**, **updateBar**, **updateBaz** gave a clear picture of what was going on in my code. **updateManyStates** is very DRY but at times I feel like it's more clever than digestible for another developer. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having nicely named methods that perform specific updates to local component state. I prefer it, actually, as these methods often get passed around to other components downstream and makes tracing the logic easier.

Calling `this.setState` in each method is hardly at odds with the notion of DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the thing to keep in mind is to try and be as consistent as possible with whatever pattern and naming standard you choose. If you think having multiple update methods creates clear, readable code, then stick with it.

Personally, I think that not only the function pattern, but also the naming standard is important to create readable code. For example, I rarely create functions with `update...` in their name, inside a Component. That naming standard is more common as an Action handler for me. What I try to do inside my components is to have methods named `handle...`, i.e. `handleChange`, `handleClick`, etc. So the call to `setState` is mostly called from within those handle function.  And if those methods are passed down to child components, they would be assigned to `on...` properties, i.e. `onChange`, `onClick`.

But to relate to your original question, since I have multiple functions as handlers, the call to setState is repeated in multiple functions and contexts.

<strike>As a side-note, I do see a problem in your example, and that is that each call to setState will replace all existing properties. For example, if you start out with the initial state</strike>

```
this.state = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
};
```

And then you call `this.setState({ foo: num )};`, then `this.state` does no longer have any `bar` or `baz` keys/values, since the entire object has been replaced. What the ReactJS documentation suggests for handling this, is to use their immutable helper function `update` (see [Immutability Helpers - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)). Depending on which React version you use, you can find it in different packages.

To only update one key/value and let the rest remain, here is what you do:

```
this.setState(update(this.state, {
  foo: { $set: "new value" }
}));
```

Here is an example of what could be a basic component from my projects.

```es6
import { updateUser } from '../actions/UserActions';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      first: "",
      last: "",
      hasChanges: false
    };

    this.handleChangeFirst = this.handleChangeFirst.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeLast = this.handleChangeLast.bind(this);
    this.handleClickSave = this.handleClickSave.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeFirst(event) {
    this.setState({
      first:      event.target.value,
      hasChanges: true
    });
  }

  handleChangeLast(event) {
    this.setState({
      last:       event.target.value,
      hasChanges: true
    });
  }

  handleClickSave() {
    const { first, last } = this.state;

    updateUser({ first, last });

    this.setState({
      hasChanges: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { first, last, hasChanges } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={first}
          onChange={this.handleChangeFirst}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={last}
          onChange={this.handleChangeLast}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Save"
          onClick={this.handleClickSave}
          disabled={!hasChanges}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And as a last tip if you are concerned about DRY-ing your code, I could achieve the same result as the above example, by binding the handle function multiple times to different attributes, like this:

```es6
constructor(props) {
  super();

  this.state = {
    first: "",
    last: ""
  };

  this.handleChangeFirst = this.handleChange.bind(this, "first");
  this.handleChangeLast = this.handleChange.bind(this, "last");
}

handleChange(attr, event) {
  this.setState(update(this.state, {
    [attr]:     event.target.value,
    hasChanges: true
  });
}
```

Maybe I overcomplicated things, but I hope this can give some ideas on how you want to structure things, going forward.

EDIT: Gave wrong information about setState.

Comment: Calling setState will make this.state have a reference to a new object but you will not lose your previous properties. setState only overwrites properties that were passed into setState. Object.assign(previousState, { foo: 3 }) for example. Also, using the setState updater function is a bit of an overkill for this example. Lastly, if you always keep in mind never to mutate your Component's state, I've never really seen the need to implement Immutable, especially for this example.

Comment: I stand corrected. I did not know `setState` worked like `Object.assign`. I have been using this pattern for so long I no longer remember where I got this assumption from. And I agree that it is overkill in that case. I edited my answer to reflect this.